# Why am I not able to use "sudo" command?

Tags: debian, sudo, root

DEBIAN 10.5.0 AMD64 DISC INSTALL -

After inserting disc for setup, I was asked to make up a "root" name and password and then asked to make up a "user" name and password.

I did, using different usernames and passwords. When I open a terminal, my "root" username shows, but when I enter the password, the terminal only accepts the "user" account's password.

If I try to do "sudo", it tells me my "root" username is not in the 'sudoers' file. I can not get into root.

Doesn’t make any sense why the terminal will not let me enter my “root” password when using sudo. I am positive I have the correct usernames and passwords.

**UPDATE 1:**

I am only able to login as a regular (non-root) user. When I open a terminal afterwards, I see the name of the terminal as my "root username@xyz" I created when installing debian. However, the password I created to go with my root username and root account, does not work. The regular user password works instead.

So I can't show you "id" when logged in as root as I can't login as root. I clicked the little message under the username that shows (where you login) and tried my root username and password multiple times, but that didn't work either.

Once in the terminal, I tried "su apt-get update" and got an error message back: "su: user apt-get does not exist".

**UPDATE 2:**
Currently, I can not post a comment so I have to write here.
I reinstalled the OS and did not create a password for "root". This caused the regular user to have "root" privileges when using "sudo". When I previously entered a password for root, I could not figure out how to "log in" as root. Lastly, you were both correct - only a 'root' password, no username.

**UPDATE 3**:
Please note -- With my 1st account, I was not able to re-log back in to the account after setting it up due to my login credentials not working for some unknown reason, so I had to create a 2nd account and then merge them together. I don't see any "solved" icon I can click to show that this message is solved. Also, I am not able to post a 'comment'. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `id` when you are logged in as this "root" user. If you are actually root, `sudo` would not ask for a password, so I think you may have created a regular, non-root user with the name "root" somehow.

Comment: `su` doesn’t work like `sudo`; you would run `su -c "apt-get update"`.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re referring to when you talk about the root username you created. During installation, there are two screens: in the first, you specify the root password (not the username or anything else — the username is always `root`), and in the second, you specify the (human) name of the first user, their login, and their password.

Comment: Please show us the output of `id`. You talk about "root username". What is that? If you show us the output of `id` we can understand what you are trying to say. Also, the command you wanted to run was `sudo apt-get update` not `su apt-get update`.

Comment: I take it your edit means this is solved? (Incidentally, why can’t you use your gregor8844 account?)

Comment: Since you seem to have solved this, I am closing the question. Now that you have registered your `gregor2` account, you should be able to comment in your posts in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of setting up the root account in Debian.

1. As you’ve done, with a separate password. By default you’ll need to use `su` to switch to root; you’ll need to set up `sudo` yourself.

   In your situation, try `su` and provide the root password — this should open a root shell. From there, you’ll be able to install `sudo` (which I suspect you’ve already done), and add your non-root user to the `sudo` group which will allow it to use `sudo` (`adduser youruser sudo`).
2. With no password, as is done by default in some other distributions. You won’t be able to log in directly as root then, but `sudo` will be installed and the initial user (configured during installation) will be able to switch to root using `sudo`.

Comment: The OP claims that when running `sudo` _as root_, they are asked for a password and told that "root" is not in sudoers, which makes me think that the root account isn't actually a root (uid=1) account. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the question is somewhat inconsistent; let’s wait for the reply to your comment on the question...